# Using JQuery why can't I output the individual array elemets generated from a DOM when I can output the complete array?

Tags: jquery, dom

If I generate an array like this

```
var elements_ar = $(".cards_my").find('img').toArray();
```

and I can output an array object like this (after reordering)

```
$(".cards_my").html(elements_ar);
```

Why can't I and how do I output the individual elements into added divs?
When I try the code I get inside the HTML and the correctly formatted div the following message which I guess means I am using an object instead of a string....

"[object HTMLImageElement]"

This is my output code

```
$(".cards_my").html(""); // to clear current contents
for (var i = 0; i < elements_ar.length - 1; i++) {
    $(".cards_my").append("<div  class='fullcard'>"+elements_ar[i]+"</div>");
}
```

Comment: In what way does it fail?  Are there any errors on the console?  Can you provide a runnable example to demonstrate?

Comment: The issue is you are trying to to string a dom element

Comment: `elements_ar[i]` is not a string. `.html()` will convert a DOM element to its HTML, but string concatenation doesn't.

Comment: @Barmar technically they would need `outerHTML`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
card_holder.append($('<div class="fullcard">').append(elements_ar[i]));
```

Don't convert the element to html.  Simply create a new div, append the element to that div, and append that div to the container.

The issue is that trying to concatenate a DOM Element to a string will result in the element being turned into `[object Object]` because string concatenation does not know how to turn a DOM Element in to html.  So to avoid the issue, we do not convert the element to html.  We simply append the element to other elements and remove the conversion out of the problem.

Comment: Taplar - I am sure we would appreciate if you cold expand on your correct answer so I and others don't make the same mistake again.

Comment: I did.  It creates a div element, appends the element_ar[i] to it, and appends that created div to the card_holder